# Screen doesn't resize properly at incoming call

Tags: ios, iphone

When a call comes in on my iPhone, my application does not resize properly. What can I do to solve handle the resize better?

Comment: Please add some more details.. what doesn't resize properly, what happens and how does it look ect.

Comment: Not an Xcode question. Retagged.

Answer (score 1):

See [Adjusting Your User Interface During a Phone Call](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW41) in the iOS App Programming Guide.